# Does rotation of a rectangle keep it rectangular?

Tags: matlab, rotations, rectangles

If I rotate a rectangle by 45°, does it stay rectangular or become something else? I mean do 90° angles stay 90°?

I am asking this question because I have some results where the rotated rectangle becomes not so rectangular ... I think I have a problem.

**Problem**: I think the problem comes from scaling.... I draw the resulting data after rotation in another image, and I have got the rectangle correctly rotated. Maybe it is because I used `imagesc` to draw the background or `axis image` in MATLAB...?

Comment: Can you explain how you get those results? Most likely the "rotations" you perform there are not worthy of that name.

Comment: If you are calculating the rotation of a rectangle, and it ceases to be a rectangle, you have a problem. :) If you are trying to rotate about the origin, use the following matrix: $$ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$$

Comment: that's what  I am using ...

Comment: I think the problem comes from scaling .... I draw the resulting data after rotation in another image and I have got the rectangle correctly rotated. maybe it is because I used `imagesc` to draw the background or `axis image` in Matlab ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found the solution.

Well, I used to draw the image using a different scaling between Y-axis and X-axis. The solution is to set `DataAspectRatio` to `[1 1 1]`. 
In order to use I have used `axis image` but **after** `imagesc(image)` !

Comment: It should be noted, that is not really the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: you are right I have to update my question ... any way It solves my problem  :) thank you for the remark

Comment: This answer helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you are not plotting at "true aspect ratio", i.e., if the horizontal and vertical scales of your plot are not identical, a rotation of the plane will not appear on the screen as an isometry; circles will appear to be non-circular ellipses, rectangles will rotated to squashed parallelograms, and so forth.

Here's a rotating square plotted at an aspect ratio of $4:1$:

[image: Rotated squares not at true aspect ratio]

Comment: How to set aspect ratio to 1:1 ? I think the function is 'daspect' right ?

Comment: @OSryx: I haven't the slightest idea, I'm afraid, just noting the likely visual issue. :)

Comment: @OSryx `axis equal`

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1306434/126407

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it stays a rectangle.

Rotations are examples of [Euclidean transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation), which preserve angles and distances. A rectangle is defined by angles (consecutive sides are at right angles), so the image of a rectangle is a rectangle.

All shapes are preserved as well, so a rectangle stays a rectangle, a circle stays a circle, an ellipse stays an ellipse, and so on. It even keeps its area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it remains a rectangle.  The best way to see this would be to draw a rectangle on a piece of paper, push your finger down on any point of that paper, and rotate the paper.  The rectangle will still be a rectangle.

Comment: Of course that is more of a physical experiment than a mathematical argument -- but as long as we don't have a formal definition of "rotate" to base a proof on, that's the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

If rectangles are rigidly rotated all lengths remain same. It looks like a parallelogram, it is due to unequal scaling factor in SF x- and y-.

In a proper rotation/translation, it is just as in a transparent polyester sheet / view graph is displaced on the table and  nothing happens relatively between line segments by scaling or distortion.

$ x1 = x \cos t - y \sin t ; \,  y1 = SF (x  \sin t + y  \cos t)  $

Aspect Ratio is to be $1$ before and after rotation.